# Correct wire and conduit to extend a 30 amp circuit 350 feet?

Tags: electrical, subpanel, conduit

I'd like to check my plan before contacting an electrician. I plan to install a 30 amp RV connection in a wet environment approximately 350 feet away from a 200 amp distribution panel. Based on voltage drop concerns, I planned to use #6 THWN in 2 inch conduit. I should have three 90-degree sweeps in the conduit run. I plan to do most of the dirt and conduit work myself. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Do not know if it is available, but for that size and distance I would search around to see if it is available in aluminum wire instead of copper.

Comment: Price 2 AWG aluminum .vs. 6 AWG copper before you go buying enough to do 350 feet. And install the conduit, measure it, THEN buy wire.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have plans to run much more out there, that's a LOT of oversized conduit to buy.

1-1/4" PVC-80 (needed where "exposed to damage" - you can use 40 where it's protected) is large enough for 3 2AWG and a 4AWG ground (standard MHF cable configuration in Aluminum.)

That gives you an extra hot wire you don't need for the 120V 30A feed, but which can be used if you want to add additional outlets or a 240V RV outlet. Percentage-wise, a 50A 240V socket actually will have slightly less voltage drop than a 30A 120V one will if fully loaded, because the voltage is doubled.

If you're sure you only ever want a 30A 120V feed you still need 1-1/4" conduit to fit the wiring, so you'd have the option to pull the 3rd 2AWG later if you don't find that MHF is so stupid-cheap you just buy all 4 as a bundle.

The 2AWG aluminum is good for 90A, but in this case what you need is the reduced voltage drop, along with "it's far less expensive than 6AWG Copper."

A reasonable approach would be to run a 30-70A breaker to a weatherproof sub-panel at the end-point, and use that to supply the 30A-120V TT connection as well as some 20A outlets on the other leg, if you run 4 wires for 240V feed. If you go with a 50A or larger supply you could put in a 50A RV socket as well. The easiest way to do all of that is a packaged ["RV panel" like this GE from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-RV-Panel-with-50-Amp-and-30-AMP-RV-Receptacles-and-a-20-Amp-GFCI-Receptacle-GE1LU532SS/203393689):

[image: GE panel]

A subpanel, whether packaged as an "RV panel" or not, can usually be fed from large aluminum wires without a problem. An individual 30A receptacle will have much lower size limits.

Comment: 2AWG is allowed to handle 90A without catching fire, yes, but if you're going to mention that, you should mention that the voltage drop for 72A at 240V at 350' (from just that section of the wire alone) will be over 6.3%. At that distance, you wouldn't want to actually breaker #2 at 90A - you'd want to go with bigger wire if you wanted to use a circuit that large.

Comment: Great, thorough answer! I'm convinced to go with Aluminum. It was suggested that I consider #1 AWG and found that the price difference is not significant. I also like the RV panel idea. Extremely helpful answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is above a certain wire size, you want to switch to aluminum wire for cost savings. Large aluminum is reliable.

I echo the recommendation for #2 aluminum.

Here's the problem with #6 copper.   You did NOT actually do a voltage drop calculation. You just applied "common wisdom" that 350’ rates two wire size increases.   The trouble is, that assumes 240V… and this is a 120V circuit!  So with #6 copper your voltage drop will be 6% at 24 amps, not so good.

We could go #4 or #2 copper but now wire costs are just getting silly.

Thus it makes perfect sense to hop over to commodity #2 aluminum.

Also, at some point you are going to graduate to a larger RV that takes 240V/50A.   And/or, you will want to charge an EV at that stand.   Now if you have three #6 and try to bring that up to four #6 for 50A, that's going to be pretty marginal due to the distance. So again you are sitting better with that #2Al.

You could push it to #1Al for not a lot more money and certainly still cheaper than any feasible copper.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now convinced that aluminum is the answer. I did check ebay as a reference and there is not that much difference between #2 and #1. I will go with #1 AWG aluminum and1 1/4" pvc rather than 2".

Comment: Thanks, I'm now convinced that aluminum is the answer. I did check ebay as a reference and there is not that much difference between #2 and #1. I will go with #1 AWG aluminum and 1 1/4" pvc.  I also re-read your answer and researched MHF as a direct buried option. That drops the cost considerably

Comment: @jonc yeah, the only suckage with MHF is the size choices are limited, #2 and 2/0 are easy to find, the intermediate sizes not so much...

Comment: @jonc with 1 AWG rather than 2 AWG 1-1/4" PVC80 will NOT allow for hot-hot-neutral ground (should you ever want it.) It will just fit hot-neutral-ground so you be limited to ONLY 120V supply (works for a 30A RV - does not work for a 50A RV, or a 30A RV and some extra sockets that don't load down the RV circuit. 1-1/2" would give you the room to use 1AWG without closing off the 240V path.

Comment: It appears my best option is direct buried MHF aluminum #2 AWG to a weatherproof RV sub panel, leaving me the option of 1 30A circuit + several sockets and a future modification to 1 50A circuit if required. What are the considerations to go with either 2/2/2/4 or 2/2/4/6?

Answer (score 0):

6AWG copper would be borderline. A [voltage drop calculator](https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=copper&necwiresize=4&necconduit=steel&necpf=0.85&material=copper&wiresize=0.4066&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=120&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=350&distanceunit=feet&amperes=24&x=Calculate&ctype=nec) shows that you will experience 6.3% voltage drop over 350 feet at 120V/24A (the maximum continuous draw for a 30A circuit, and "30A travel trailer" hookups are 120V). 5% is the general guideline for maximum desirable voltage drop. That's assuming you start with a full 120V at the supply panel bus bar, and not accounting for the RV cord or internal wiring. Distance from your local utility step down transformer, RV cord length, etc. will all add to that to some degree.

You should consider switching to aluminum because it's far less expensive for the same ampacity, and then bump up a size (4AWG aluminum would be equivalent to 6AWG copper, 2AWG is a step up in ampacity). #2 USE cable, sold as "mobile home feeder" is particularly effective (due to economies of scale) - a 4-wire cable (giving you the option to do 240V later if you need) should be about half the price of only three 6AWG copper wires. Voltage drop for 24A at 120V on 2AWG aluminum over 350 feel will be under 4.5%.